# How to display weeks in a table with previous and next buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I got the below code to get the current week dates and display on the html table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#"> << </a> </td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="#"> >> </a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
$ts = date(strtotime('last sunday'));
$dow = date('w' , $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1 ;

    if($offset < 0 ){
    $offset = 0 ;
        }

$ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
for ($x=0 ; $x<7 ; $x++,$ts += 86400) {
echo '<td>' . date("m-d-Y", $ts) . '</td>' ;
    }
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is working fine starting with "Sunday" and hows the current week dates.
But i am using "Next" and "Previous" buttons/links to dis play the next week and the last week.

But i am unable to display the previous week details and next week dates. Also once the previous or next week dates are retrieved it should keep on continue without any error for X number of weeks.

How can i do this with PHP/mysql.
Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Ashan.

Comment: Are you using `mysql`? It seems like your buttons only execute client side so maybe do this with javascript? Or build your output before outputting and put the start date as the previous button, and the end date in the next button. Then on the next page you will now where to start/finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one. Some sort of pagination:

```
<?php

    (int)$currentpage = (!empty($_GET["currentpage"]))?$_GET["currentpage"]:0;
    (int)$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    (int)$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage"; ?>"> << </a> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage"; ?>"> >> </a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $ts = date(strtotime('last sunday'));
            $ts += $currentpage * 86400 * 7;
            $dow = date('w' , $ts);
            $offset = $dow;

            $ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
            for ($x=0 ; $x<7 ; $x++,$ts += 86400) {
                echo '<td>' . date("m-d-Y", $ts) . '</td>' ;
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```